# Shipping folders in perl6 Modules

Tags: raku

I am currently having the same issue that melezhik has explained in his ticket at the bailador project. https://github.com/Bailador/Bailador/issues/309.
I want to write a module App::Something that is Cro based which should ship a few files and **folders**. Taken from the comments on this post the `$?RESOURCE` "flattens" the contents of directory down to single files.

Do you have a smart idea how to provide access to folder structures shipped in modules?

Comment: What do you plan to do with such a folder? Certainly not put stuff into it after-the-fact I hope, which defeats the purpose of installation altogether.

Comment: No I would not putt stuff into it after the installation, of course. The directories I am talking about are supposed to be read only. For a Bailador or Cro app, I assume, this would typically be templates, images, css files, javascript stuff, fonts maybe. For a different application this could be anything else.

Comment: Then there should be nothing stopping someone from using `%?RESOURCES` and declaring the contents saved under the `resources/` folder e.g. `resources/view/bar.js`

Comment: Well, what is stopping me is for example how Cro and Bailador access to those content. For cro it is for example via the `static` keyword https://cro.services/docs/intro/spa-with-cro#Serving_a_static_page. For Bailador it can be done via the `views` or `layout` directory, See https://github.com/Bailador/Bailador/blob/dev/doc/README.md#templates. I don't see how access to $?RESOURCES could help me out here.

Comment: You are going to have to be more clear in what you are asking -- not docs on web frameworks existing paradigms. At the very least it sounds like you expect an exact file system representation, but all files of all modules are stored in a single flat directory using special file names. As the application developer you have access to `%?RESOURCES` and can probably e.g. `static $_.IO.absolute for %?RESOURCES.values`. Its not going to act like a directory for you though.

Comment: You are right. I've updated my question a little bit in order to make it more clear.

Comment: Would it be a stupid idea to write a `ResourceExtractor` that reads the keys of `$?RESOURCES` and creates a temporary directory and recreates the hirachical structure of all resources in this directory?

Comment: Actually it might be a good idea for Cro to understand `%?RESOURCES` rather than re-create the directory.

Comment: I think recreating the directory is indeed the wrong thing to do. IMHO there need to be a (documented) way of instrospecting %RESOURCES so that programms can "understand" %?RESOURCES better.